# IIS 7.0 returning 500 error against incoming post from libwww-perl server

Tags: asp.net, perl, post, iis-7

I am tasked with handling a POST from a vendor. I was unable to configure WCF to accept posts after trying [wcf service doesn't allow POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930742/wcf-service-doesnt-allow-post) and also posting for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295863/wsdl-iis-7-post-not-working

So I decided to use a plain asp.net website and set up a form (.aspx) for receiving the cross-domain post. I can make a cross-domain post from either ajax or an asp.net webform being run out of a different domain. My logs show 200 responses from the web server and VS 2010 goes right into my breakpoint.

However the posts coming from the real vendor's server are erroring out with an HTTP 500.

Here is the log excerpt with a dummied up IP address.

----SUCCESSFULL HTTP 200 X-DOMAIN POST BY ME - aspx to aspx ---

---

---VENDOR FAILURE HTTP 500 ---------

2012-07-03 17:20:33 99.999.999.999 POST /ecapproval.aspx - 80 - 64.38.241.33 - 500 0 0 733
2012-07-03 17:21:23 99.999.999.999 POST /ecapproval.aspx - 80 - 64.38.241.33 libwww-perl/5.837 500 0 0 357
2012-07-03 17:21:41 99.999.999.999 POST /ecdenial.aspx - 80 - 64.38.241.33 - 500 0 0 728

They are not posting a form as I am to test nor ajax. Again both work. They are using a non MSFT server and I am guessing PERL is the language initiating the post. At any rate I'd be grateful for any advice how I can use .NET to receive this post.

Thanks!!

Comment: The 500 error is coming from ASP.NET. You'll need to track down the actual application error, not the IIS log files. I'd suggest using something like Wireshark to trace the packets and see what error is being returned to the libwww-perl client.